# Не уничтожается пуля C# Unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пуля уничтожается только при соприкосновении с игроком, а с препятствиями - нет. Все теги расставлены корректно, я проверил. Что делать? код прилагаю ниже:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class projectile : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed;

    private Transform player;
    private Vector2 target;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        target = new Vector2(player.position.x, player.position.y);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }
    void Destroy()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D shit)
    {
        if (shit.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Destroy();
        }
        if (shit.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            Destroy();
        }
        if (shit.gameObject.tag == "zona")
        {
            Destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Какие коллайдеры на объектах? Возможно на игроке, например, BoxCollider2D, а на остальных BoxCollider. Поэтому и не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно пуля летит слишком быстро, для толщины коллайдеров твоих препятствий. В кадр до столкновения пуля еще до препятствия , а кадр после уже за коллайдером препятствия. Здесь можно попробовать включить Continious.Dynamic режим для детектирования коллизий. Он гораздо более тяжелый , чем дискретный.. Можно из пули луч пускать Physics.Raycast на расстояние, которое пуля пролетит примерно за один кадр (bullet.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime) ..  ну и дальше смотреть 'видит' ли пуля тот же объект , что и кадр назад или нет.. если нет, то пролетела значит. Тут много нюансов может быть с последним подходом.

Может быть у тебя просто на игроке есть RigidBody и поэтому триггер срабатывает https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html. Как вариант попробуй добавить на пулю RigidBody, только не забудь включить IsKinematic, потому что ты двигаешь ее 'через координаты' (MoveTowards)..

А может у тебя тупо слои не участвуют в коллизиях друг с другом. Посмотри в ProjectSettings -> Physics. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html

И я бы не уничтожал пулю, а просто клал ее в пул, чтобы потом заного использовать. Destroy это дорого и ни к чему здесь..